# How to URL-encode the the whole xml value of a query param using Spring's rest template?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot application

I need to make a request to an external service, old and ill-conceived. The request take the form of a HTTP GET (or POST) call, but the payload, an xml content, need to be passed as a query parameter. For example,

```
GET http://ill-service.com/plain.cgi?XML_DATA=<request attribute="attributeValue"><content contentAttribute="plain"/></request>
```

Of course, the value of query param XML_DATA need to be URL encoded, and normally, the RestTemplate of Spring boot work good on that, following  RFC 3986 (see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

Except that, as allowed by this RFC, '/' and '=' character are left in the param value, giving me the following query :

```
GET http://ill-service.com/plain.cgi?XML_DATA=%3Crequest%20attribute=%22attributeValue%22%3E%3Ccontent%20contentAttribute=%22plain%22/%3E%3C/request%3E
```

In a perfect wold, this would be good, but do you remember when I said that the service I am trying to call is ill-conceived ? In another world, it needs to have the **full** content of XML_DATA URL-encoded. In another words, it needs the following query:

```
GET http://ill-service.com/plain.cgi?XML_DATA=%3Crequest%20attribute%3D%22attributeValue%22%3E%3Ccontent%20contentAttribute%3D%22plain%22%2F%3E%3C%2Frequest%3E%0A
```

I am quite lost on how to instruct the rest template or the UriComponentBuilder I am using to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of Vasif, and some information about UriComponentBuilder I found the following solutions :

```
String xmlContent = "<request attribute="attributeValue"><content contentAttribute="plain"/></request>";

URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://ill-service.com/plain.cgi")
    //This part set the query param as a full encoded value, not as query value encoded
    .queryParam("XML_DATA", UriUtils.encode(xmlContent, "UTF-8"))
    //The build(true) indicate to the builder that the Uri is already encoded
    .build(true).toUri();

String responseStr = restTemplate.getForObject(uri ,String.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably u can use spring's `UriUtils` class

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.net.URLEncoder` to encode your `XML` payload first and then append the encoded payload.